# If I am not an administrator but I want to read the registry, what is easiest way to do it?

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, regedit

When I open regedit in Windows 7, I get

> "Registry editing has been disabled by your administrator"

Can I open it someway in readonly mode?
Or does anyone know how can I see values in  the registry?

Comment: This means your system administrator has disabled registry editing through Group Policy. The computer I'm using now is affected by said condition; using reg cmd tools does not work either. You will not be able to read or write to the registry

Comment: I wish they was a read-only mode, I want to check something in the registry without having to worry about accidently changing something.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Non-administrators have the same registry 'read' rights as administrators.

You also have full write access (Full Control) to the HKEY_CURRENT_USER key.

**To open the registry:**

- Open the Windows Start Menu
- Type in **"regedit"** and press **'Enter'** on the keyboard
  [image]
- Workstations which are a member of a domain will prompt for a password - just enter the password for your non-administrator account.
  [image]

**Please note**:

- Some sections of the registry are locked to all users (Admin or Non-Admin), for example HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SECURITY
- If your system is configured to disallow the use of 'regedit' you will need to speak with your system administrator. Giving advice on how to circumvent this would be unethical and likely against the superuser terms of use.

Answer (score 6):

Use `reg query` in cmd. It does not need admin privileges.

Comment: And neither does `regedit`; it's a matter of group policy restrictions, which I assume both `regedit` and `reg` follow.

Comment: @grawity As a default, (and therefore for computers that are not part of a domain, and have no group policy set), reg query works, and regedit does not.

Comment: I've used `regedit` as a User on Windows 95, 98, NT 4.0, 2000, XP, Vista, and 7.

Comment: @grawity, I dont know what settings you were operating under, so I can't comment. In either case, my answer is not wrong, it just may not be needed.

Answer (score 2):

Probably your administrator had disabled from group policy the right of opening registry editors.

Go to Run » `gpedit.msc` » User Configuration » Administrative Templates » System » "Prevent access to registry editing tools". Disable it or choose "Not Configured".

The main problem is that `reg query` doesn't work, giving the same error:

> ERROR: Registry editing has been disabled by your administrator.

… or this sounds to me as a bug in Windows 7. On Windows XP, `reg query` is working fine, without any problem if "Prevent access to registry editing tools" is Enabled.