# HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion missing from Registry Editor

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, regedit

On my brand new laptop I am trying to disable some Windows shortcut <kbd>Win-S</kbd>, <kbd>Win-D</kbd>, <kbd>Win-C</kbd> and <kbd>Win-X</kbd> like I usually do on all my other computers. Only this time, the Registry entry `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion` is missing.

The usual process would be to add `DisabledHotkeys` StringValue in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced` with any letter as the value.
I tried to create these entries manually then rebooting, but it doesn't work. Am I missing something?

**td;dr** `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\CurrentVersion` is missing from the Registry on my brand new laptop.

> Dell XPS 15 9500 (2020), Win10 OS Build 19041.508

Comment: It is in Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the author has indicated they have already solved their problem y running the registry editor has the appropriate user with elevated permissions

Comment: If you mean below registry entry: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced

Comment: You can post that as an answer to your own question, for others to find.

Comment: Dear close-voters: I’m all in favor of closing questions that are founded on (pardon the terminology) *stupid* misconceptions and typos, like «I typed `registryedit` and the computer said “'registryedit' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.”»   I don’t see this as a stupid misconception.   The fact that the user has answered their own question is not a reason to close.

Answer (score -1):

Fixed it by running Registry Editor as Administrator. Some entries were hidden.

Comment: Is this even possible?  The registry editor will not run unless it is elevated.   Something else occurred here.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas: Huh? I don’t have access to a Windows 10 machine ATM, but the registry editor has always worked in non-privileged mode before. Yes, of course you need elevated privileges to *modify* HKLM, HKCR, etc., but you normally have full access to HKCU.

Comment: @Scott, technically you don't need rights to HKCU.. you are right.  But the MANIFEST embedded in regedit.exe says that it requires elevation unless something has changed since I last tried.  Try opening regedit.exe without admin rights and TELL ME WHAT HAPPENS before telling me I am wrong.  See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16370317/accessing-regedit-without-admin-rights) also.  And no, it hasn't always worked in non-priv mode.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas: Well, I did try it before posting the previous comment.  But I just did it again, to double-check.  Running Windows 7 Professional (yeah, I know), with default UAC configuration, logged in as my ordinary, non-admin user.  Last time I ran it from the Start Menu; this time I ran `regedit` from a (non-elevated) Command Prompt.  (CMD immediately issues another prompt, as is typical when you invoke a GUI program.)  Either way, “Registry Editor” window opens (no UAC dialog), showing the last key (in HKCU) that I edited.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  I verified that I can still create, modify and delete values in that key, and create and delete new keys, without providing admin credentials.  Also I could access and modify HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced.  Then I randomly chose a key under HKLM and verified that I could not make write there. … … … But also, I clearly remember several years ago (probably between 2005 and 2009) being similarly able to run `regedit` (and `regedt32`) at work on machines where I didn’t have admin access.  (I don’t specifically recall the Windows version(s), … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  but I’m fairly sure of the date range, so I guess that must have been before Windows 7.) … … … … … … … … … … See also [this comment](https://superuser.com/q/308693/150988#comment328376_308711) (by the ***very***-high-rep user [formerly known as grawity](https://web.archive.org/web/20191113144551/https://superuser.com/users/1686/grawity)): “I've used `regedit` as a User on Windows 95, 98, NT 4.0, 2000, XP, Vista, and 7.”  And [user743382’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16370317/1672723#16371721) to the question you linked to confirms my experience. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … But, yeah, I may have gone too far when I said “always”.  As the Super User thread that I just linked to discusses, `regedit` can be restricted by policy.  OTOH, I believe that that has nothing to do with the program’s manifest. … … … … … … … … … … On the third hand, it seems like there might be variables we aren’t accounting for, as different people seem to get inconsistent results. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  P.S. I agree with you to this extent: The user should not have been able to get into `regedit` (and, presumably, see part of HKCU) and not have access to (or even ***see***) HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion.  There’s more going on here than has been revealed. … … … … … P.P.S. Congratulations on finding yet another question on Stack Exchange that should have been migrated to Super User!

Comment: I am a little embarrassed.. I guess i always assumed becuase of the UAC when you are an administrator. You are right @Scott.